# Tkinter different screens

Tags: python, tkinter

I created an app in tkinter (python) but when I  open my app in different screen( laptop or PC), the app show me the information cuts.

I used .place(x= , y= ) to position my labels and bottoms.

Any idea how can I open my app with their correct positions?

Comment: It may be caused by different system display scaling factors.

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that your Tkinter application displays correctly on different screens, consider using alternative layout managers such as pack() or grid() instead of absolute positioning with place(). These layout managers are more flexible and can adapt to different screen sizes and resolutions more effectively.
As using absolute positioning with place() can sometimes result in issues with layout when the application is displayed on different screens or devices with varying resolutions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think this is actually a clear answer in spite of what the community bot says.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot position your application correctly, you can try this code:

```
screen_width = app.winfo_screenwidth() screen_height =
app.winfo_screenheight()
app.geometry(f"{WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}+{((screen_width-{WIDTH})//2)}+{((screen_height-{HEIGHT})//2)}")
```

If you cannot position the elements in the application correctly, you can try using the `width` and `height` parameters of the place method.